# NPV function using dplyrs group operator

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to `group_by` an `ID` and perform a NPV caluclation from the `FinancialMath` package (or create the NPV myself).

The data looks like:

```
    ID         CF otherVar date
1   78   83739.63     0.00 1989
2  100   21421.77     0.00 1989
3  987   89581.94 46926.38 1989
4 1934 2921150.05  5597.58 1989
5   78   83739.63     0.00 1989
6  100   21421.77     0.00 1989
```

Where CF is the cash flows.

I am trying

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(npv = NPV("date == 1989" then "date == 1992"...))
```

but I do not know how to represent the data in the NPV calculation.

```
i <- c(0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.02)

library(FinancialMath)
#The NPV function takes the arguments:
NPV(cf0,cf,times,i,plot=FALSE)
```

Any help would be great.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(78, 100, 987, 1934, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 
78, 100, 987, 1934, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 78, 
100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 
1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 
78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 
987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 
2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 
100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 
1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 
78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 987, 1934, 2938, 78, 100, 
987, 1934, 2938), CF = c(83739.6348934691, 21421.7670657712, 
89581.9350023158, 2921150.05442334, 83739.6348934691, 21421.7670657712, 
89581.9350023158, 2921150.05442334, 83739.6348934691, 21421.7670657712, 
89581.9350023158, 2921150.05442334, 83739.6348934691, 21421.7670657712, 
89581.9350023158, 2921150.05442334, 83739.6348934691, 21421.7670657712, 
89581.9350023158, 2921150.05442334, 36094.1785878537, 49844.341859417, 
103126.224536725, 1481580.09251095, 17187.7040894541, 36094.1785878537, 
49844.341859417, 103126.224536725, 1481580.09251095, 17187.7040894541, 
36094.1785878537, 49844.341859417, 103126.224536725, 1481580.09251095, 
17187.7040894541, 36094.1785878537, 49844.341859417, 103126.224536725, 
1481580.09251095, 17187.7040894541, 36094.1785878537, 49844.341859417, 
103126.224536725, 1481580.09251095, 17187.7040894541, 11065.7431065623, 
97827.5839855509, 259804.403371463, 19244.7706201084, 83394.0060204696, 
5613.05809753161, 97827.5839855509, 259804.403371463, 19244.7706201084, 
83394.0060204696, 9943.13148705599, 97827.5839855509, 259804.403371463, 
19244.7706201084, 83394.0060204696, 13952.4586995786, 97827.5839855509, 
259804.403371463, 19244.7706201084, 83394.0060204696, 7697.90824804335, 
97827.5839855509, 259804.403371463, 19244.7706201084, 83394.0060204696, 
483026.595362645, 16449.8221330932, 672.947269081084, 2646925.92505227, 
249738.208747869, 876326.888181145, 31404.2058904506, 672.947269081084, 
6011662.27045769, 273665.222759641, 912217.409198803, 28413.3291389791, 
672.947269081084, 3215192.50783185, 320023.812407449, 856886.189296581, 
32899.6442661863, 672.947269081084, 7058469.13347271, 158516.467827989, 
480035.718611173, 14954.3837573574, 672.947269081084, 5413486.92016339, 
608643.418924447, 58523.7787123908, 156063.409899709, 41802.6990802791, 
164423.949715765, 94752.7845819661, 57130.3554097148, 156063.409899709, 
41802.6990802791, 164423.949715765, 94752.7845819661, 58523.7787123908, 
157456.833202385, 41802.6990802791, 164423.949715765, 94752.7845819661, 
57130.3554097148, 157456.833202385, 41802.6990802791, 164423.949715765, 
94752.7845819661, 58523.7787123908, 157456.833202385, 41802.6990802791, 
164423.949715765, 94752.7845819661), otherVar = c(0, 0, 46926.3808521831, 
5597.58022093635, 0, 0, 46926.3808521831, 5597.58022093635, 0, 
0, 46926.3808521831, 5597.58022093635, 0, 0, 46926.3808521831, 
5597.58022093635, 0, 0, 46926.3808521831, 5597.58022093635, 3773.40425531915, 
58026.5721040189, 148420.567375887, 922387.706855792, 8385.34278959811, 
3773.40425531915, 58026.5721040189, 148420.567375887, 922387.706855792, 
8385.34278959811, 3773.40425531915, 58026.5721040189, 148420.567375887, 
922387.706855792, 8385.34278959811, 3773.40425531915, 58026.5721040189, 
148420.567375887, 922387.706855792, 8385.34278959811, 3773.40425531915, 
58026.5721040189, 148420.567375887, 922387.706855792, 8385.34278959811, 
0, 111186.313465784, 186197.924944812, 50112.1412803532, 96935.6732891832, 
0, 111186.313465784, 185054.741721854, 50112.1412803532, 96935.6732891832, 
0, 111186.313465784, 186260.565121413, 50112.1412803532, 96935.6732891832, 
0, 111186.313465784, 185571.523178808, 50112.1412803532, 96935.6732891832, 
0, 111186.313465784, 185133.041942605, 50112.1412803532, 96935.6732891832, 
900029.118136439, 0, 0, 462655.541805324, 0, 568051.164725458, 
0, 0, 496059.163477537, 0, 522311.980033278, 0, 0, 399829.082986689, 
0, 752483.361064892, 0, 0, 431831.757695507, 0, 522311.980033278, 
0, 0, 447496.690723794, 0, 514.843391902215, 350906.417112299, 
84000.7639419404, 208647.058823529, 0, 514.843391902215, 350906.417112299, 
84000.7639419404, 252002.291825821, 0, 514.843391902215, 350906.417112299, 
84000.7639419404, 173420.932009167, 0, 514.843391902215, 350906.417112299, 
84000.7639419404, 136839.954163484, 0, 514.843391902215, 350906.417112299, 
84000.7639419404, 283163.865546218, 0), date = c(1989, 1989, 
1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 
1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001)), row.names = c(NA, 
-120L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002621ef0>, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be doable by calculating the discount factor for each row, and using that to discount each cash flow. In this case, I am discounting back to the first year (ie what was the net present value in 1989), but it wasn't clear to me if that's what you're looking for. If you want to find the present value in current money, assuming the `rate` of constant return, replace `min(date)` with a reference year of your choice.

```
rate = 0.05
data %>%
  mutate(period = date - min(date),
         discount = 1 / (1+rate) ^ period,
         CF_disc = CF * discount) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(NPV = sum(CF_disc))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
     ID       NPV
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1    78  3098073.
2   100  1204245.
3   987  1981237.
4  1934 37228043.
5  2938  1687395.
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this Works for what I was trying to achieve.